# "ifort: no match" error in csh script

Tags: fortran, csh, fortran77

I'm trying to compile a program called ZEUS and I am following the included instructions exactly but I came across the following error.

The instructions asked me to type `csh -v namelist.s` in the folder containing `namelist.s`. This is a fairly large assembly file which invokes another file given in the source files called `bldlibo` which is the csh file mentioned in the title. The contents of this file are:

```
#==== SCRIPT TO BUILD AN OBJECT LIBRARY FROM A FORTRAN SOURCE FILE====#
#
#    Syntax:  bldlibo <library name> <source code>
#    eg:      bldlibo namelist.a namelist.f
#
rm -rf bldlibo.dir
mkdir bldlibo.dir
cp $2 bldlibo.dir
cd bldlibo.dir
fsplit $2 >& /dev/null
rm $2
#
#  When -fast option is used, this leads to the __vsincos_ unsatisfied
#  external errors when zeus is compiled with -g option.  Thus, use -O4
#  instead.
#
ifort -c -O4 *.f
#f77 -c -g -C -ftrap=common *.f
ar rv $1 *.o >& /dev/null
ranlib $1
cd ..
mv bldlibo.dir/$1 .
rm -r bldlibo.dir
```

When I run `csh -v namelist.s` it begins to run `bldlibo` and works fine up until ifort is invoked at which point it says `ifort: no match`. I have tried adding `#!/bin/csh` at the start and also `source .../ifortvars.csh` but that didn't work.

Can anybody help me, sorry if I haven't explained it well enough.

Comment: Do you have any files matching `*.f` in the directory where ifort is run?

Comment: The file ` bldlibo`  is in the home directory, ` *.f `  files are in a folder called ` editor`  and the ` namelist.s`  file is in a folder called ` nmlist` . The ` *.f` files have already been used to create a preliminary executable.